# node.js add array of images into corresponding array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs

I'm new in node.js and I'm getting some data from database (actions). Every action has a number of images registered in another table so that I can get them by action id.

I'm trying to add an array of these images to the correponding action so that I can loop through them in the frontend.

In php I use to do like this:

```
    $return = array();
    $images = array();
    $image = array();

    $select = "SELECT id, title, description FROM actions WHERE id = ? order by id DESC";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($select);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $description);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $registers = array(
            "id" => $id, "title" => $title, "description" => $description, "images" => $image
        );

        $selectImages = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id, image FROM action_images WHERE action_id = '" . $id . "' ");
        while ($row = $selectImages->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

            $images = array("imageID" => $row['id'], "image" => $row['image']);
            array_push($registers["images"], $images);
        }
        
        $return[] = $registers;

    }
```

Is there something similar in javscript/node.js? I tried some things described in the code below but nothing worked as expected.

This is my controller:

```
async selectActions(req, res) {

        let actionData = [];

        conn.execute('SELECT * FROM actions',
            function (err, results, fields) {

                // console.log(err);
                // console.log(results);

                if (err == null) {

                    results.forEach(action => {
                        conn.execute('SELECT * FROM actions_images WHERE actionID = ?',
                            [action.id],
                            function (imagesError, imagesResults, ImagesFields) {

                                // I've tried some things like:
                                actionData = [results, imagesResults];
                                // and
                                actionData = [...results, ...imagesResults]
                                // and
                                results.push(imagesResults)
                                // but nothing had the expected results displayed in the image below
                                console.log(actionData);
                            }
                        );
                    });

                    return res.json(results);
                } else {
                    return res.json('error fetching actions from database: ' + err);
                }
            });

    },
```

Action images array must be another item in each action item:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Promise.all(results.map((action, index) => {
    return Promise(resolve => {
        conn.execute('SELECT * FROM actions_images WHERE actionID = ?',
            [action.id],
            function(imagesError, imagesResults, ImagesFields) {
                results[index].action_images = imagesResults;
                resolve(true);
            }
        );
    })

}))
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Hi. I got this error: `TypeError: undefined is not a promise`

Comment: I added a `new` to this line `return new Promise(resolve => {` and I got a console but no images array was added. It´s returning just the actions

Comment: Ok I did this: `action['images'] = imagesResults;` in my original function and it worked. But I have to set a timeout to wait until array is filled. I tried it too in your function but no images are added to action array.